# Bluetooth only recognized after waking from suspend

Tags: bluetooth

My bluetooth only works after suspending my computer. See just after starting my computer the output of rfkill list all is:

```
  $ rfkill list all
  0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

Then I suspend it (here I use pm-suspend, but the GUI method works too)

```
  # pm-suspend
```

and voilà, rfkill list all again

```
  $ rfkill list all
  0: phy0: Wireless LAN
       Soft blocked: no
       Hard blocked: no
  1: hci0: Bluetooth
       Soft blocked: no
       Hard blocked: no
```

the output of lspci is

```
$ lspci
  00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
  00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
  00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
  00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
  00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
  00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
  00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
  00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
  00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
  00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
  00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 04)
  00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
  01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5289 (rev 01)
  01:00.2 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0a)
  02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 (rev c4)
```

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it work without suspend if you `sudo modprobe -r btusb && sleep 5 && sudo modprobe btusb`

Comment: Is there any solution to this problem? I am having the exact problem with ubuntu 20.04. Turning off and on again btusb via modprobe is not working.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem solved itself when upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04. Sorry I cannot give more details. Before (years ago) when I used linuxmint with the same computer I did not have this problem which came when I switched to ubuntu (I think it was 16.04 back then), so there must be a way to solve this.

Good luck

Comment: +1 for the dedication of coming back to answer after almost 5 years